# Complex request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a API made with Node.js. 
I am using express, Mongodb and I have to create a route with a complex data structure.

like this:

```
{
  title: String,
  description: String,
  photo: Data Image,
  list: [
  {
    title: String,
    photo: Data Image
  },
  ....
  ]
}
```

So I have some information like title and description.
Then I have a photo and a list of objects, which can contains a photo, and a title.

So my question is how can I design my route for a such request?

Do I have to separate l'upload of the photos separately ?

What is the best design for a such structure (server <-> client) ?

Comment: Your question seems too board, have you test with some codes? or search some sample codes?

Comment: No I didn't, my case is very specific. I am trying to find what is the best practice to send image via an API. But the question is, do I have to perform a single request for the whole data or separate it. I am a little bit confused right here.

Comment: Please describe your issue in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client, send your complex data structure as the body of the request.

Your route can be something like:

```
// POST /albums
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var album = req.body; //this is the data sent in the body of the request
    // do whatever you want with 'album'
});
```

In your app.js, include:

`app.use(require('body-parser').json()) // needed to parse the body to json format`

and

`app.use('/albums', require('./routes/albums')); // mount your route`

Plese, note that you should put the require statements on the top of the file, on separated variables.

If you want to update an album, your route should be:

```
// PUT /albums/:id
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var albumId = req.params.id; // this is the id to update
    var album = req.body; // this is the data sent in the body of the request
    // do whatever you want with 'album'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds good.